# Jenkins build error with aws codepipeline and S3

Tags: jenkins, amazon-s3, aws-codepipeline

I was putting a CI CD pipeline with Git to S3 to build on Jenkins and using aws pipeline plugin in Jenkins for publishing.

I was running into this Jenkins error and I am pretty new with Jenkins and not knowing what's going on.

Can someone please help?

```
Started by an SCM change
Building in workspace /var/lib/jenkins/workspace/harrystage1
[AWS CodePipeline Plugin] Job 'c841b4be-5ba8-41c3-aac3-3fecdc7e6226' received
[AWS CodePipeline Plugin] Acknowledged job with ID: c841b4be-5ba8-41c3-aac3-3fecdc7e6226
[AWS CodePipeline Plugin] Detected compression type: Zip
[AWS CodePipeline Plugin] Successfully downloaded artifact from AWS CodePipeline
[AWS CodePipeline Plugin] Extracting '/var/lib/jenkins/workspace/harrystage1/dZM1xh9.zip' to '/var/lib/jenkins/workspace/harrystage1'
[AWS CodePipeline Plugin] Failed to acquire artifacts: The compressed input file contains files targeting an invalid destination: ./
[AWS CodePipeline Plugin] Stacktrace:
[AWS CodePipeline Plugin] com.amazonaws.codepipeline.jenkinsplugin.ExtractionTools.getDestinationFile(ExtractionTools.java:114)
[AWS CodePipeline Plugin] com.amazonaws.codepipeline.jenkinsplugin.ExtractionTools.extractZipFile(ExtractionTools.java:70)
[AWS CodePipeline Plugin] com.amazonaws.codepipeline.jenkinsplugin.ExtractionTools.extractZip(ExtractionTools.java:46)
[AWS CodePipeline Plugin] com.amazonaws.codepipeline.jenkinsplugin.ExtractionTools.decompressFile(ExtractionTools.java:176)
[AWS CodePipeline Plugin] com.amazonaws.codepipeline.jenkinsplugin.DownloadCallable.downloadAndExtract(DownloadCallable.java:127)
[AWS CodePipeline Plugin] com.amazonaws.codepipeline.jenkinsplugin.DownloadCallable.invoke(DownloadCallable.java:87)
[AWS CodePipeline Plugin] com.amazonaws.codepipeline.jenkinsplugin.DownloadCallable.invoke(DownloadCallable.java:36)
[AWS CodePipeline Plugin] hudson.FilePath.act(FilePath.java:997)
[AWS CodePipeline Plugin] hudson.FilePath.act(FilePath.java:975)
[AWS CodePipeline Plugin] com.amazonaws.codepipeline.jenkinsplugin.AWSCodePipelineSCM.checkout(AWSCodePipelineSCM.java:234)
[AWS CodePipeline Plugin] hudson.model.AbstractProject.checkout(AbstractProject.java:1212)
[AWS CodePipeline Plugin] hudson.model.AbstractBuild$AbstractBuildExecution.defaultCheckout(AbstractBuild.java:560)
[AWS CodePipeline Plugin] jenkins.scm.SCMCheckoutStrategy.checkout(SCMCheckoutStrategy.java:86)
[AWS CodePipeline Plugin] hudson.model.AbstractBuild$AbstractBuildExecution.run(AbstractBuild.java:485)
[AWS CodePipeline Plugin] hudson.model.Run.execute(Run.java:1735)
[AWS CodePipeline Plugin] hudson.model.FreeStyleBuild.run(FreeStyleBuild.java:43)
[AWS CodePipeline Plugin] hudson.model.ResourceController.execute(ResourceController.java:97)
[AWS CodePipeline Plugin] hudson.model.Executor.run(Executor.java:415)
[AWS CodePipeline Plugin] 

Build was aborted
[AWS CodePipeline Plugin] Publishing artifacts
[AWS CodePipeline Plugin] Artifact names in the Jenkins project do not match output artifacts in the pipeline action. Either configure the artifact name of each location to match output artifacts for the pipeline action, or leave the field blank. [Pipeline: harrystage1, stage: Build, action: Build].
[AWS CodePipeline Plugin] Stacktrace:
[AWS CodePipeline Plugin] com.amazonaws.codepipeline.jenkinsplugin.AWSCodePipelinePublisher.perform(AWSCodePipelinePublisher.java:154)
[AWS CodePipeline Plugin] hudson.tasks.BuildStepMonitor$2.perform(BuildStepMonitor.java:32)
[AWS CodePipeline Plugin] hudson.model.AbstractBuild$AbstractBuildExecution.perform(AbstractBuild.java:730)
[AWS CodePipeline Plugin] hudson.model.AbstractBuild$AbstractBuildExecution.performAllBuildSteps(AbstractBuild.java:676)
[AWS CodePipeline Plugin] hudson.model.Build$BuildExecution.post2(Build.java:186)
[AWS CodePipeline Plugin] hudson.model.AbstractBuild$AbstractBuildExecution.post(AbstractBuild.java:621)
[AWS CodePipeline Plugin] hudson.model.Run.execute(Run.java:1760)
[AWS CodePipeline Plugin] hudson.model.FreeStyleBuild.run(FreeStyleBuild.java:43)
[AWS CodePipeline Plugin] hudson.model.ResourceController.execute(ResourceController.java:97)
[AWS CodePipeline Plugin] hudson.model.Executor.run(Executor.java:415)
[AWS CodePipeline Plugin] 

[AWS CodePipeline Plugin] Build failed, calling PutJobFailureResult
Build step 'AWS CodePipeline Publisher' marked build as failure
Finished: ABORTED
```

Answer (score 0):

If your build has multiple outputs you can define which artifact in your pipeline Jenkins should upload each local artifact to.

The outputs you specify in your Jenkins configuration must match the output names on the Jenkins action in your pipeline.

Answer (score 0):

You need to specify the output artifact in the aws code pipeline build stage and map that artifact name in the Jenkins job code pipeline publisher section.
[image]

[image]